How do Tikz-3D local planes work?
I am trying to use the canvas system to define scopes with local planes.
When defining a local plane, according to the documentation we define:

plane origin=⟨point⟩ Origin of the plane


plane x=⟨point⟩ Unit vector of the x-direction in the new plane


plane y=⟨point⟩ Unit vector of the y-direction in the new plane

So the default plane (in 3D) should be : plane origin = (0,0,0), plane x = (1,0,0), plane y = (0,1,0)
If I run this code, I should get a green vector corresponding to the x direction starting from the origin, and the same vector in red starting from (0,3)
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {3d, angles, calc, patterns, quotes, math}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,green] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[right] {$\vec u_x$};
\begin{scope}[plane x = {(1,0,0)},
                plane y = {(0,1,0)},
                plane origin = {(0,3,0)},
                canvas is plane,
                transform shape]; 
    \draw[->,red] (0,0) -- (1,0) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But I get this and I can't figure out why (3D/2D conversions... ??)


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thank you very much !

The unit vectors are from the plane's origin, so you need to allow for the transformation of the plane because this hasn't happened yet. That is, the new origin plus the two coordinates together determine the orientation and location of the plane, so they must all be specified in the old coordinate system for the transformation to be successfully defined.
So,
  \begin{scope}[%
      plane x = {(1,3,0)},
      plane y = {(0,3,1)},
      plane origin = {(0,3,0)},
      canvas is plane,
      transform shape
    ]

produces the desired result:

\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {3d, angles, calc, patterns, quotes, math}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,green] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[right] {$\vec u_x$};
  \begin{scope}[%
      plane x = {(1,3,0)},
      plane y = {(0,3,1)},
      plane origin = {(0,3,0)},
      canvas is plane,
      transform shape
    ]
    \draw[->,red] (0,0) -- (1,0) ;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you for your response, however i don't understand the logic. And why plane plane y = {(0,3,1)} instead of plane y = {(0,4,0)}. So you are telling me that the plane_x vector in the reference plane "O" is calculated as : plane x|O = plane x|O' - plane origin|O where O' is the locally defined plane ? I don't get the logic at all behind that because this operation does not translate a vector

@gabyy_rx try drawing the axes with your original code. the z axis runs up the page and the y is projecting out from the page. this always seems odd to me, but I assumed it was standard and didn't seem strange to people who use this stuff all the time. (I use it occasionally, but not frequently, so I just figured I was insufficiently expert to get it.)

Well, it's strange. My y runs up and my z projects out of the page
